# How do I change the cursor align of a text field?

Tags: flutter

I'm making a flutter app that supports two languages and I want to be able to change the cursor alignment of a text field depending on the language which the user types in.

so the problem is the cursor is by default is left aligned and for example when I type in Arabic which is RTL and even when I'm setting the text-align to end and text direction to RTL the cursor will be fortunately aligned to the right but when I enter a new line it will be on the left until I actually type some text.

so I want to control the cursor align value, Is it possible?

```
TextField(
 textAlign: _translator.primaryLanguage == 'arabic'
  ? TextAlign.end
  : TextAlign.start,
 textDirection: _translator.primaryLanguage == 'arabic'
  ? TextDirection.rtl
  : TextDirection.ltr,
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Directionality(
    textDirection:
        _translator.primaryLanguage == 'arabic' ?
            TextDirection.rtl
            : TextDirection.ltr,
    child: TextField(
     ...
    ),
)
```

Comment: the same problem appears